# Recursive methods

Tags: visual-studio-2010, recursion, windbg

I'm having a hard time grasping recursion. For example I have the following method. When the if statement returns true, I expect to return from this method. However looking at the method execution in Windbg and Visual Studio shows that the method continues to execute. I apologize for the generic question however your feedback would really be appreciated.

How is N decremented in-order to satisfy the if condition?

```
long factorial(int N)
{
    if(N == 1)
        return 1;
    return N * factorial(N - 1);
}
```

Comment: If you want to understand recursion in WinDbg, type `.dbgdbg` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

compiling and disassembling the function you should get a disassembly similar to this

```
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'uf fact!fact;q'
fact!fact:
00401000 55              push    ebp
00401001 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
00401003 837d0801        cmp     dword ptr [ebp+8],1
00401007 7507            jne     fact!fact+0x10 (00401010)

fact!fact+0x9:
00401009 b801000000      mov     eax,1
0040100e eb13            jmp     fact!fact+0x23 (00401023)

fact!fact+0x10:
00401010 8b4508          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]
00401013 83e801          sub     eax,1
00401016 50              push    eax
00401017 e8e4ffffff      call    fact!fact (00401000)
0040101c 83c404          add     esp,4
0040101f 0faf4508        imul    eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]

fact!fact+0x23:
00401023 5d              pop     ebp
00401024 c3              ret
quit:
```

lets assume N == 5 when the function is entered  ie [ebp+8] will hold 5 
as long as [ebp+8] > 1 the jne will be taken

here you can see N being decremented (sub eax ,1)
the decremented N is again passed to the function fact  (recursed without a return back to caller)  the loop happens again and the decremented N is resent to fact  this keeps on happening until the jne is not taken that is until N or [ebp+8] == 1

when N becomes 1  jne is not taken but jmp 401023 is taken 
where it returns to the caller the caller being the function fact(int N)

that is it will return 40101c where the multiplication of eax of takes place and result is stored back in eax;

this will keep on happening  until the ret points to the first call in main() see the stack below prior to executing pop ebp for the first time

```
0:000> kPL
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0013ff38 0040101c fact!fact(
            int N = 0n1)+0x23
0013ff44 0040101c fact!fact(
            int N = 0n2)+0x1c
0013ff50 0040101c fact!fact(
            int N = 0n3)+0x1c
0013ff5c 0040101c fact!fact(
            int N = 0n4)+0x1c
0013ff68 0040109f fact!fact(
            int N = 0n5)+0x1c
0013ff78 0040140b fact!main(
            int argc = 0n2, 
            char ** argv = 0x00033ac0)+0x6f
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to grasp is to work through your code manually. Say you call factorial(4), what happens?4 is not equal to 1. Return 4 * factorial(4-1).

What is the return value of factorial 3? 3 is not equal to 1 return 3* factorial(3-1).

What is the return value of factorial 2? 2 is not equal to 1 return 2* factorial(2-1).

What is the return value of factorial 1? 1 equals 1 is true. Return 1. This is the base case.  Now we move back up the recursion. 
Return 1. This is factorial (2-1)
Return 2*1. This is factorial (3-1)
Return 3*2 this is factorial(4-1)
Return 4*6 this is factorial(4), the original call you made.

The idea is you have a function that has a base case (when n=1 return 1) and the function calls itself in way that moves the function towards the base case (factorial(n**-**1)).